# WebSecurityConfig Java equivalent for spring LDAP authentication done with spring-security.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I implemented the LDAP authentication and authorization using Spring Security in my project. I configured the spring-security.xml and got it running. I am trying to do the same using Java (WebSecurityConfig.java). Can someone guide me on how to do this?

```
Here is my spring-security.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  >

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/common" access="hasRole('role.xyz.WebAdmin')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admincare" access="hasRole('role.xyz.WebAdmin')"/>

        <security:form-login
                login-page="/auth/login" 
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true" 
                default-target-url="/main/common"/>

        <security:logout 
                invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/auth/login" 
                logout-url="/auth/logout"/>

    </security:http>


            <security:authentication-manager>

        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="ldapContext" />
                <property name="userSearch">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                        <constructor-arg name="searchBase" value="" />
                        <constructor-arg name="searchFilter" value="(&amp;(uid={0})(objectclass=person)(ums-account-state=OK))" />
                        <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="ldapContext" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.gemalto.mobileid.service.UmsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="ldapContext"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <security:ldap-server id="ldapContext" url="ldap://aaa:54389/dc=xxx.com" manager-dn="bbb" manager-password="ccc" /> 
</beans>
```

Now, if I want to do same in the JAVA style (in WebSecurityConfig.java) and get rid of the XML, how do I do? I am not so familiar with the APIs provided for this. I started it this way:

```
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("", "ldap://aaa:54389/dc=xxx.com");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerListener loggerListener() {
        return new LoggerListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Configuration for Redirects, Login-Page and stuff

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admincare").authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin();
            //.loginPage("/auth/login")
            //.permitAll();     
    }
```

I am not sure how to set the rest of the parameters (as done in XML) in this Java code for the WebSecurityConfig. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try this :-

```
    @Bean
    public BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource() {
    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://aaa:54389/dc=xxx.com");
    contextSource.setUserDn("bbb");
    contextSource.setPassword("ccc");
    return contextSource;
    }


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .and()
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new UmsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource()))
                .and()
                .userSearchBase("").userSearchFilter("(&(uid={0})(objectclass=person)(ums-account-state=OK))");
         }            


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {              
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/main/common**","/admincare**").hasRole("role.xyz.WebAdmin")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login").failureUrl("/auth/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/main/common")
            .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login").logoutUrl("/auth/logout");    
    }
```

Comment: Hi Avis, thanks a lot for your help. This works very well for authentication (when I specify like:.antMatchers("/admincare").authenticated(). But if I were to use the hasRole I get Access denied. And that is because I need to be able to add my custom UrsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator that I need to use. See the reference in the spring-security.xml above. Do you know how I can add it?

Comment: This populator class implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator             {private final BaseLdapPathContextSource source;

  public UmsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(BaseLdapPathContextSource source) {
    this.source = source;
  }

Comment: Thanks Avis, it works perfectly. Would you know if there is a way to avoid having to give managerdn and managerPassword we gave above? If yes, how could that be achieved and what changes will be required?

Comment: What I meant was if there is a way to do this without having to give the userdn and password like we give in the context source above. I think that is still a manager-dn and password. I have heard and read that we should not provide it. I am not sure what changes are required for that though

Comment: In order to login into any ldap server one need to have managerDn/userDn along with password else it wont remain secured and anybody can login.